# Blender export as dae file contains broken 3D render

Tags: export, dae

*General information*
Blender version: **2.79**

I am currently working on an animated 3D model that I will be using in a game being coded in Scenekit. I'm currently facing the issue where my exported 3D model turns out to be "broken".

Here is a picture of what the render should look like.
[image: render]

This is what happens when I export it as a **.dae** **.fbx** or even **.obj**. As you're able to tell the cape surrounding the character is "broken". I'd like to know what I can do to resolve this problem or what I'm doing wrong.
[image: render]

How I export the 3D render in Blender: *file -> export -> .dae*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like the [face normals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) are facing different ways. Game engines use [backface culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling) to only draw one side of a polygon.

In edit mode select all <kbd>A</kbd> and use <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> or <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to [set the normals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html#editing) to the same direction.

You may also want to look at not using backface culling so that both sides of the robe are visible in your game.